# Automated tests for databinding (MVVM)

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests

How do i create automated tests to check if events of an UI component call the correct methods in my code (especially for WPF/MVVM)?

Is there another "way to go" to test GUIs in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: How would a computer know what method is "correct" for an event? For example, if your button click event is tied to method `TriggerDoomsdayWeapon()`, how would you specify that it is correct or not, in a way that the computer understands, and that adds anything over the definition in XAML?

Comment: Obviously i would need to specify what is the "correct" method. Even though this would be a lot of work, it would be worth it for me to verify that the databinding is working correctly and my events are actually firing when they are supposed to. I generally do not like "clickdummy" tests and would like to test my gui in another way if possible.